# How to work with objects of other layout in mainactivity android

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

i have 2 different layouts in my android program and i want to switch between them sometimes. but at first my program is terminating and does't work because layout 2 objects are not defined. how can i fix this?

```
        // d and z are obejcts of another layout

    Button mainButton1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.d);
    final TextView myTextView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.z);

    mainButton1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0)
        {
            myTextView1.setText("Bye!");
        }
    });
```

Comment: You can only find Views on the Layout that has been inflated with `setContentView()` (in an Activity)

Comment: Are you using 2 layouts in a single activity?

Comment: i can show the another layout but how can i control it? i mean that i show another layout but how can i program for objects which located in that layout?

Answer (score 0):

Set the Id's for all views before using them in your Activity.

Answer (score 0):

you cannot do that because before using the elements of the xml file we have to give the reference to that xml file, otherwise it will through null pointer exception. If you have to pass some information to other activity you can attach it with the intent you are using to start other activity
Hope it helps